# When should I use "as.xxx" v. "create an object"?

Tags: r

So I see for a lot of objects in R there are 2 ways to create an object. For example, for a `zoo` object there is `zoo(....)` and `as.zoo(....)`. It looks like the former is an object instantion and the latter a casting construct.

In common languages like C,Java,C# you usually use the casting operator for casting between objects within the same line of inheritance, i.e. cast child to parent classes. You would `create a new object` if you have a compositional structure (many objects inside 1 object) instead of inheritance.

In R it seems I can pass a dataframe to either `zoo(....)` and `as.zoo(....)` and get a zoo object. So when should I use the `create object` v. using `as.xxx`?

Comment: Related [Difference between as.data.frame(x) and data.frame(x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574250/difference-between-as-data-framex-and-data-framex)

Comment: Each package can define functions however they like. Is this specifically about `zoo`? If not, it's pretty much impossible to answer.

Comment: Is there a general guideline when to use "as.xxx" or when to create an object?

Comment: No. You just need to read the documentation for each of the different functions for each package to see which is appropriate. Maybe you can say generally you use `as()` when converting an object from one class to another and the non-as-version when creating an object "from scratch." They sometimes expect different input values. But you should read the docs for any function you plan to use.

Comment: RTFM is not my forte. Isn't there a convention I can follow?